# Using multiple MATLAB session with a single GPU

Tags: matlab, gpu

I have a single GPU and would like to use multiple MATLAB sessions (I have multiple licenses for each session) that can access the same GPU. I see that I can do this without much fuss. But my question is, will there be an issue of data corruption in such a case?

Comment: Obviously you tried something of that sort already right? then what did you discovered? what exactly have you tried?

Comment: I have a custom kernel to do convolution and I test this to while running another MATLAB procedure that constantly uses the GPU. I did not see any error in my testing, the error between the MATLAB implementation and the GPU implementation is 1e-13.

However, what I would like to know is what happens when I run two things that are running concurrently for long? What is the mechanism MATLAB uses so that I can understand if there will be any corruption of the data?